# How to write this in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

How would I write the following using HAML?

```
if @students.each do |student|
  # render a student
end.empty?
  # @students was empty
end
```

Comment: Have you *tried*? it's 95% HAML already. You just need some `-`'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear as though you can use `end` in haml though this is not widely known. Here's the final code:

```
- if @students.each do |student|
  # render a student
- end.empty?
  # @students was empty
```

*If anyone knows of where the use of `end` is documented in HAML, please update this answer*

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't.  You'd write

```haml
- if @students.any?
  - @students.each do |student|
    = # render a student
- else  
  = # @students was empty
```

---

**Update**

While I cannot find any reference to this in the documentation, HAML actually *does* allow for a `- end.method` chaining, so your code should work as written, with the addition of some dashes and the removal of the final `end`.

```
- if @students.each do |student|
  # render a student
- end.empty?
  # @students was empty
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking for. I want to use the `if..end.empty?` trick.

Comment: You can't, there is no `end` in HAML. Also, that's a *bad* trick. Just use if/else.

Comment: I don't see how that's a bad trick. It's still very readable in my opinion. Also, `end` _does_ seem to work in HAML. I tried it and all seems well.

Comment: Have you tried it? HAML will raise a `Haml::SyntaxError` which says very clearly `You don't need to use "- end" in Haml.`

Comment: No error. Tried it and it's working.

Comment: Shut my *mouth*, you are absolutely correct. HAML *does* allow for `- end` so long as you're chaining additional methods off of it.

Comment: I had no idea you could use `end`. I learned something new today and it's only 9:50AM ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this out:-

```
- unless @students.empty?
  - @students.each do |student|
    = render a student
- else
  = render other stuff
```